# WSUS with proxy that requires authentication

Tags: windows-xp, proxy, wsus

I have a Windows XP system that needs to connect to a remote WSUS server to get updates.  This system can only access the server through a proxy that requires a user name and password.  I don't have the option of setting up a local WSUS server.

How can I configure the WSUS client to use the proxy and also pass it the username and password in order to connect to the WSUS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. WSUS and Windows Update don't have this capability. You'll probably have to do something like set up a VPN on the remote system so that it can get to your WSUS server.

Comment: Could I set up a local proxy server on the client that supports authentication, point the local proxy to the remote proxy with the authentication, then point WSUS to use the local proxy?

Comment: @JonS that's entirely dependent on whether or not your proxy solution allows that type of configuration. That's outside the scope of this question and is outside of my realm of expertise. As far as your question is concerned, though, WSUS does not contain this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what proxy you are using you should be able to whitelist the WSUS server and that would allow the clients to connect to WSUS w/out authentication.